# difficulties with prooving: K is a vector space over Z/pZ

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

I am trying to solve the followong exercise:

Given is K as a field with finitely many elements.

i) show that K is a vector space over $\mathbb{F}_p:=\mathbb{Z/p\mathbb{Z}}$,  for some special values of p. (Hint: use Fundamental theorem on homomorphisms for rings).

Here I thought, that p should be a prime number in order to fulfill  firstly the condition for inverse elements. But how should I use here the theorem?
Or should I better go through all the conditions?

ii) Show that K has a finite base as a $\mathbb{F}_p $ vector space.

Well, that means to me , that I should be able to get every element in $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ with such a group of generators and this group should be the smallest of all possible. It means, that all the elements between 1 and (p-1) could produce a one element base, for example {1}. Is that right? So the dimension would be in this case 1

iii) find out the amount of elements in K in dependence from its dimension as $\mathbb{F}_p $ vector space.
Here I only see p elements in the field without any connection to the dimension..
Thank you

Comment: Do you believe $K$ is a finite extension of $\mathbb{F_p}$?  Is it then an algebraic extension?  Is there then an "obvious" basis for $K$?

Comment: I am a first year student and sitting in the lecture for begginers
only. I haven't heard anything about extensions...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the map $\eta:\Bbb Z\to K$ given by $1\mapsto 1_K$. The ideal $\{0\}$ is prime in $K$ so $f^{-1}(0)=\ker \eta$ is prime in $\Bbb Z$. Since $K$ is finite, this is nontrivial, so $\ker \eta=(p)$ for some prime $p$. Thus we have an injection $\bar\eta:\frac{\Bbb Z}{p\Bbb Z}\to K$ for some $p$, that is $\Bbb F_p$ is a subfield of $K$. You can in fact show that $$p=\min\{k>0:\underbrace{1+\cdots+1}_{k\;\rm times} =0\}$$ and that $\Bbb F_p$ is the smallest subfield of $K$ w.r.t. inclusion, the so called "prime subfield", $=\bigcap \{F\subseteq K:F\text{ is a field }\}$

Now $(K,+)$ is an abelian group, and we have an action $\Bbb F_p\times K\to K$ such that $(a,b)\mapsto ab$, since $a,b$ are elements of $K$. Since $K$ is finite, and $|K|=|\Bbb F_p|^{\dim K}$, $\dim K$ must be finite.